# What is the worst case for A* search algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, a-star

Under what conditions will the A* search algorithm explore all the states in the search space?
Is this the worst case?

According to me, it will be forced to search the entire search space if f(n) for each node on the route to the goal, is higher than the other nodes on the same level.
This is the worst case since all the nodes generated must be expanded to reach the goal.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a):

> The time complexity of A* depends on the heuristic. In the worst case, the number of nodes expanded is exponential in the length of the solution (the shortest path), but it is polynomial when the search space is a tree, there is a single goal state, and the heuristic function h meets a certain criteria:

Comment: Could you explain this with a particular case in hand in which the algorithm explores all the states in the search space (considering a tree where only 1 goal state exists)

Comment: That's actually a very cool guarantee! However in the typical case of planar (or low dimensional) spaces, the search would be polynomial even without a heuristic.